# Wo liegt der Unterscheid zwischen Prostituierte und Nutte im stillistischen Sinne?

Tags: meaning

Welches Wort ist als Beleidigung zu fassen?

Comment: 1) Bitte stelle die Frage im Körper und nicht nur im Titel. 2) hast du in einem Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen? Wörterbücher haben in der Regel erklärende Abkürzungen wie *abw.*

Answer (score 3):

Dazu lohnt ein kurzer Blick in den [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nutte):

> Nut­te, die
>   Wortart: Substantiv, feminin
>   Gebrauch: salopp abwertend

Zu Prostituierte findet sich kein Hinweis zum Gebrauch:

> Pro­s­ti­tu­ier­te
>   Wortart: substantiviertes Adjektiv, feminin

Nutte ist also stets abwertend, Prostituierte ist als Wort an sich neutral, kann jedoch im Kontext abwertend sein. Die meisten Damen möchten vermutlich weder als Nutte noch als Prostituierte bezeichnet werden (sofern sie dem Gewerbe nicht nachgehen).

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Frage. Es gibt eine [tour] der Seite. Offengebliebene Fragen, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [help].

Comment: Es wäre möglicherweise angebracht, den Begriff "Hure" zu erwähnen, der an sich ebenso wie "Nutte" gemeinhin abwertend verwendet wird und den Prostituiertenverbände aber als Selbstbezeichnung (damit also ohne Wertung) verwenden.

Comment: Die meisten Damen müchten wahrscheinlich auch nicht als Hausangestellte bezeichnet werden, wenn sie es nicht sind. Abwertend ist bei Prostituierte die Tatsachenbehauptung, nicht die Wortwahl.

Comment: @userunknown Ich behaupte, das steht genauso in der Antwort?